# How to catch Sign in with Apple response with browser when iOS signed in with AppleID?

Tags: ios, oauth, apple-id

I made login page with "Sign in with Apple" button previously, however its behaviour seems strange and now I'm finding for any solution.

**Browser in computer**

"Sign in with Apple" jumps to Apple's authentication page.

**Browser in iOS (not signed-in)**

"Sign in with Apple" jumps to Apple's authentication page.

**App in iOS (not signed-in)**

"Sign in with Apple" starts iOS native modal to input Apple account.

**App in iOS (signed-in with Apple)**

"Sign in with Apple" starts iOS native modal to confirm the operation.

**[PROBLEM] Browser in iOS (signed-in with Apple)**

"Sign in with Apple" starts iOS native modal to confirm the operation, and after that, it never come back to the browser and operation cannot finish....

I use directly the URL `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?` with enough parameters. Any suggestion is welcome. I beg your help !!

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, it's my totally ridiculous mistake.

iOS modal passes only `%20` for whitespace character, but it used `+` instead.

It works now.

Thank you so much for your support !